# AudioSession input from bluetooth output to line out or speaker

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiosession, audiosession

Once an audio session has been set up the following code allows bluetooth input.

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof (allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);
```

This code looks like it only allows bluetooth input however this code also routes the audio output to the bluetooth device (in the case of a bluetooth headset). I would like to route the audio output out of the line out or speaker when the input is coming from a bluetooth device. I just want to get audio input from a bluetooth device, I do not want to output audio via bluetooth.

Is this behaviour possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as of iOS 5 this behaviour is not possible, quoting apple technical support

> Bluetooth devices are not "Jacked In" devices and therefore any other
>   audio routing must be user picked and cannot be changed in code. To do
>   this, you can use the functionality of the MPVolumeView which will
>   have an extra routing widget viewable allowing the user to specify the
>   routing of the output.
>
> There's a older thread on the Core Audio mailing list regarding this
>   functionality but behavior hasn't changed:
>
> http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Oct/msg00030.html
>
> MPVolumeView reference:
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

However the MPVolumeView does not allow you to route the input and output independently.