# iOS - How to record a video using a bluetooth headset as audio input?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, avfoundation, video-recording

I'm trying to record a video using [DIYCam](https://github.com/thisandagain/cam) and setting the audio route for a bluetooth headset as audio input, but seems like the routing isn't working. As I understand, I just need to route the audio input to my bluetooth headset, and I don't need to change anything about DIYCam, am I right? Here is my code:

When the view is loading I create the DIYCam instance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    self.camera = [[DIYCam alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.camera.delegate = self;
    [self.camera setupWithOptions:nil]; // Check DIYAV.h for options
    [self.camera setCamMode:DIYAVModeVideo];
    [self.view addSubview:self.camera];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.camera];

    if( self.bluetoothInput ) {
        [self setBluetoothAudioInput];
    }
}
```

This is my bluetooth routing function:

```
- (void)setBluetoothAudioInput
{
    // create and set up the audio session
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setDelegate:self];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    // set up for bluetooth microphone input
    UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
    OSStatus stat = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                                             sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                                             &allowBluetoothInput
                                             );
}
```

And these are the IBActions for starting and stoping:

```
- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender
{
    [self.camera startSession];
    [self.camera captureVideoStart];
}

- (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender
{
    [self.camera captureVideoStop];
    [self.camera stopSession];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have the user manually set what input device to use for audio.  I just had a similar issue and used an MPVolumeView with the showsVolumeSlider boolean set to NO.  This provides a clickable button to set the desired input from a list of available ones.

Check out:
[AudioSession input from bluetooth output to line out or speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305986/audiosession-input-from-bluetooth-output-to-line-out-or-speaker)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
```